# Using a custom fomula in Google spreadsheets based on another cell value

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

I would like to have certain cells change color based on the value for `D1`.

There are only two possible values for `D1`, `55` or `65`.  (`D1` is a value derived from a function, not sure if that matters).

What I want is if `B4>=D1` background is green, `B4<D1` background is red regardless of the value of `D1`.

So, there are four possible outcomes: `B4>=65` (green), `B4<65` (red), `B4>=55` (green), `B4<55` (red).

How do should this formula look and can it work for a range of cells?

Answer (score 0):

It seems as though you just want red except when B4 is greater than or equal to D1.

Assuming the relevant range is ColumnB select it and fill (normal) with red. That way ColumnB is red regardless of the content (or not!) of B4 and D1, which we can then conditionally overrule to turn green.

Select ColumnB then choose `Custom formula is` in the *Format → Conditional formatting...* dialog and enter:

```
=B$4>=$D$1
```

And for Background Colour: select green. Range: should already be set to B:B.

Comment: Thanks for the help!  It seems that I tried to make the formula overly complicated.